# Can't edit code in visual studio 2013 while running

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I'm developing a web site in VS2013 Update 2 with .net 2.0 using IIS as web server. My problem is that when I run the web site, i can't edit it. Not trying to edit and continue nor edit while debbuging. I'm saying that once the page is completed loaded on web browser, i cant change anything on source files(.vb) until i stop and run the project again.

Something strange is that i formated my pc recently and after i reinstalled everything it was working. Then, VS chrashed and on the next start the problem appeared.

Comment: Can't you edit the code even when it's paused?

Comment: nope. Have to stop the execution, edit and then continue. I cant debug, VS stops on breakpoints, however i can't edit anything if the project isn't stoped

Comment: Isn't your process x64 by any chance?

Comment: just set iis to run under 32 bits, problem stills there

Comment: Now it's getting interesting. Do you get any error messages or just "can't edit"?

Comment: Not getting errors, the code is read only

Answer (score 1):

that is normal. you cannot edit .vb or files that get compiled when it is running. You can however edit the html, javascript, css files even when it is running since those files are not compiled.

Comment: i did it when i just installed VS

Comment: You can try going to the project properties and then web. check enable edit and continue.

Comment: This is so dumb... :(

Answer (score 0):

To enable *edit and continue* in *vs2013*, you need to check edit and continue in `mvc project property > Web` (scroll until reach end of options) and disable or uncheck *edit and continue* in `Tools > Option > Debugging > edit` and `continue > uncheck`.

Then build the application and run the project.
This should now work when you change the controller (tested)

Answer (score 0):

Open your project using option 'Open->Web Site' then you will able to edit your code while vs2013 is running.
Do not open solution file because it is not allow this option